# Why is my buffered observable completing rather than supplying a value for my onNext at each interval?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I have an Observable called `processedMessages`. I need to buffer those messages and delete them from an external queue every 10 messages, or every 30 seconds. I  have the following code which is *supposed* to accomplish this task:

```
this.processedMessages.Where(m => m != null && some criteria here)
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 10, this.schedulerProvider.Concurrent)
    .Subscribe(
        (observer) => { DeleteMessages(observer); });
```

This code is called by my service's constructor. At the time of the first call `processedMessages` is an empty observable. `Messages` are potentially added to `processedMessages` as long as the service is running. I need this to continue deleting messages so long as they're being added to `processedMessages`. Instead this code runs once (not even respecting the 30 second delay), calls DeleteMessages immediately and then completes.

I've tried wrapping the whole thing in an `Observable.Create()` and subscribing to that later. That runs the code once but never repeats. I've tried adding `Repeat()` on various sub observables (admittedly verging on cargo culting there), but that either puts me in an infinite loop, or continues deleting the same messages over and over.

I suspect that my problem lies in the fact that I never call `.Subscribe()` on `processedMessages` itself; only on the Buffered projection. But if I have to subscribe to that observable, what's the point of the Buffer extension method at all?

**EDIT:**

Based on Shlomo's answer, here's how I've created `processedMessages`.

I tried both of the following and only realized after considering in detail what they're doing that both options create an observable with a single message and then complete:

```
this.processedMessages.Concat(Observable.Return(newMessage));

this.processedMessages.Concat(new List<IMessage>() { newMessage }).ToObservable();
```

So then the correct followup question would seem to be: How do I add new messages to `processedMessages` without causing it to complete prematurely?

Answer (score 0):

Your observable as posted should trigger `DeleteMessages` on one of three conditions:

1. 10 messages have arrived since subscription or the last trigger
2. 30 seconds have elapsed since subscription or the last trigger
3. Observable `processedMessages` completes.

Since there's no visibility into `processedMessages` I cannot debug further.